# How to infer function params with object type explicitly defined

Tags: typescript

Not sure what the best wording of this was, please feel free to suggest a better title. Here's the example:

```
type Query = ((...params: any[]) => Promise<any>);

type Resource = {
  query: Query;
}

export type Params<T> = T extends ((...params: infer R) => Promise<any>) ? R : any[];

const resource: Resource = {
  query: (id: string) => Promise.resolve(id)
}

const inferredResource = {
  query: (id: string) => Promise.resolve(id)
}

type ResourceParams = Params<typeof resource['query']>;
type InferredResourceParams = Params<typeof inferredResource['query']>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiKBeKAKDA6XYCGi+AtgM4BcU+AdiANoC6AlGgHxQAKiA9sQJakIAHhohWTANwBYAFCzQkKACUIpbnEQBjaOgDesqFACOCZJXhIQ0mQF9ZsiAA8w3RMCgLoHQiVJCAKuzo-lBOwBDUACakmDh4PmSUfNQAZkjKLKjsXLwCwqLiUAD8ylCUoozWsprc1KTuiKrqWhCUKmoa2mhQ+jKGJpaUGHyRlPWIyQDmmdk8-ILYjWoANgBuEMORTLJ2cjI1de7JaYiNke3NXXoGxqYgQyNjwBPU02ycc3mLTWsbI9u2ewyTzKJqdCDeIhkbqQ3xCTzcFJQJaXCB0ADkA2Q6IYrGsIIAkqkkGcLuDYdD0BS-AikccSRBzmCWhisSAcXigA)

The problem I have is that the first example's shape is defined by `Resource`, which is great because then I know what parameters are required and what shape they need to have.

But, the `ResourceParams` inference now doesn't work, so I can't retrieve the type of those params later on.

In the second example (`inferredResource`), the inference DOES work, but now I don't get the type safety of knowing the resource is of the correct shape.

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds here? I want to know the object I have is conforming to this shape, but I still want to infer its properties.

Comment: 1. Your playground link is truncated.  2. You can simplify `new Promise...` to `Promise.resolve(id)`.

Comment: The playground link works for me.

Comment: Did for me on third attempt!

Answer (score 0):

NB: There is a standard utility type, [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)<>, which does what your `Params` does (in a slightly different way).

The problem here is a misunderstanding of where you are getting the type from.  Whilst Query allows for any function returning Promise to be assigned, the actual type of Resource.query is still as per Query - i.e. `any[]`.

With the inferred type, you get the actual supplied parameter type (string) because there is nothing else.  `inferredParams` is still the same shape as Query (as `id: string` can be accepted as part of `...args: any[]`), and so would be treated as having the Query interface.

Thus, `ResourceParams` is `any[]`, and `InferredResourceParams` is `id: string`

Comment: I understand why it's not inferring the type. What I'm wondering is how I can fix `Query` (and/or `Resource`) such that the parameters are inferred, instead of being defined as `any`.

Comment: No, because that's what they are.  Query is defined as any[], so how would it produce a different result?  The inferred version is working from different information. I'm struggling to see a use case for matching function parameters, and perhaps you can reformulate (ask a new question) that specifically asks for what you want, with examples.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to write `const resource: Resource = { ... }` and have that object constrained by a generic shape (so that, e.g. `resource.query` must return a `Promise`), but to infer the parameters of the `query` function.

The reason I want to be able to infer those, is because I want to be able to pass this object into a function and return a function that requires those same parameters.

Comment: Understood.  I can't see how that can be done, even with generics supplying the parameter types, which isn't easy if you need them to be completely arbitrary.  I'm still wondering what the wider use case is, because generally the only way to handle arbitrary parameters is to access any[] and internally check the count and types to disambiguate.  I can't see how you can apply type safety to that, without widening the type to catch all cases.  Have you looked at class method overloads?